# In which scripture, does Sage Narada ask for the boon that Lord Rama's name be the superior of all names?

Tags: scripture, rama, padma-purana, vishnu-sahasranama

[Moonstar2001](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/1195/moonstar2001) in response to [a question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19815/why-are-the-names-of-shri-krishna-and-rama-superior-to-the-name-of-lord-vishnu) said:

> There is a story that in one of the rama avataras, sage Narada asked Rama for the boon that the name "Rama" be more potent than any other names of the lord. Rama granted him this wish.

Now in which scripture is this story mentioned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The story of Narada asking the above-mentioned boon from Lord Rama is described in [Chapter 126 (pg 723)](http://cincinnatitemple.com/articles/Sri-Ram-Charit-Manas-Hindi-Text-Eng-Translation.pdf) of the **Aranya-Kanda of Ramacharitmanas.** Sanskrit text taken from [here](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_otherlang_hindi/manas3_i.html?lang=sa).

Narada goes to meet Lord Rama because he feels that he may not get the chance to meet him again.

> मोर साप करि अंगीकारा। सहत राम नाना दुख भारा ॥  ऐसे प्रभुहि बिलोकउँ
>   जाई। पुनि न बनिहि अस अवसरु आई ॥
>
> mora såpa kari amgikårå, sahata råma nånå dukha bhårå.3. aise prabhuhi
>   bilokau° jåi, puni na banihi asa avasaru åi.
>
> "It is in submission to my curse that the Lord is undergoing many
>   hardships of an oppressive nature. Let me, therefore, go and see such
>   a noble Lord; for such an opportunity may not present itself again"
>
> यह बिचारि नारद कर बीना। गए जहाँ प्रभु सुख आसीना ॥  गावत राम चरित मृदु
>   बानी। प्रेम सहित बहु भाँति बखानी ॥
>
> yaha bicåri nårada kara binå, gae jahån prabhu sukha åsinå.4. gåvata
>   råma carita mrdu båni, prema sahita bahu bhåti bakhåni.
>
> Reflecting thus Nårada went, lute in hand, to the spot where the Lord
>   was sitting at ease. He fondly sang in a soft voice the exploits of
>   Lord Råma dwelling upon them in all detail.

After this welcome, Narada asks Rama for the boon that His name surpass all other names in their potency and destroy thousands of sins.

> दो.   नाना बिधि बिनती करि प्रभु प्रसन्न जियँ जानि। 
>         नारद बोले बचन तब जोरि सरोरुह पानि ॥ ४१ ॥
>
> nånå bidhi binati kari prabhu prasanna jiya jåni, nårada bole bacana
>   taba jori saroruha påni.41
>
> After much supplication and realizing that the Lord was pleased at
>   heart, Nårada joined his lotus palms and spoke as follows:-
>
> सुनहु उदार सहज रघुनायक। सुंदर अगम सुगम बर दायक ॥  देहु एक बर मागउँ
>   स्वामी। जद्यपि जानत अंतरजामी ॥
>
> sunahu udåra sahaja raghunåyaka, sundara agama sugama bara dåyaka.
>   dehu eka bara mågau° svåmi, jadyapi jånata antarajåmi.1
>
> Listen, O Lord of Raghus, generous by nature as You are: You confer
>   delightful boons that are unattainable as well as those that are
>   attainable.  **Grant me, my master, only one boon that I ask of You,
>   even though You already know it (even without my asking), indwelling
>   as You do the hearts of all.**
>
> जानहु मुनि तुम्ह मोर सुभाऊ। जन सन कबहुँ कि करउँ दुराऊ ॥  कवन बस्तु असि
>   प्रिय मोहि लागी। जो मुनिबर न सकहु तुम्ह मागी ॥
>
> jånahu muni tumha mora subhåu, jana sana kabahu ki karau duråµu.
>   kavana bastu asi priya mohi lågi, jo munibara na sakahu tumha mågi.2.
>
> **You know my disposition, dear sage: do I ever hide anything from my
>   devotees? What object do I hold so dear, O chief of sages, that you
>   may not ask it of Me ?**

> जन कहुँ कछु अदेय नहिं मोरें। अस बिस्वास तजहु जनि भोरें ॥  तब नारद बोले
>   हरषाई । अस बर मागउँ करउँ ढिठाई ॥
>
> jana kahu kachu adeya nahi more, asa bisvåsa tajahu jani bhore. taba
>   nårada bole harasåi, asa bara mågau karau dhithai.3.
>
> **There is nothing which I may withhold from my votary: never give up
>   this belief even by mistake.**
>
> **Then Nårada gladly said, This is the boon I presume to ask:**
>
> जद्यपि प्रभु के नाम अनेका। श्रुति कह अधिक एक तें एका ॥  **राम सकल नामन्ह
>   ते अधिका**। होउ नाथ अघ खग गन बधिका ॥
>
> jadyapi prabhu ke nåma anekå, sruti kaha adhika eka te ekå. **råma
>   sakala nåmanha te adhikå,** hou nåtha agha khaga gana badhikå.4.
>
> **Even though my lord has many names, each greater than the rest, as the
>   Vedas declare, let the name RÅMA, my lord, surpass all other names in
>   exterminating the whole brood of sins even as a fowler kills an entire
>   flock of birds.**
>
> दो.  राका रजनी भगति तव राम नाम सोइ सोम। 
>         अपर नाम उडगन बिमल बसुहुँ भगत उर ब्योम ॥ ४२(क) ॥
>
> råkå rajan∂ bhagati tava råma nåma soi soma, apara nåma uŒagana bimala
>   basahu bhagata ura byoma. 42(A)
>
> **May the name RÅMA shine as the moon and the other names as so many
>   stars in the cloudless sky of Your devotees heart during the full-moon
>   night of devotion to You.**
>
> एवमस्तु मुनि सन कहेउ कृपासिंधु रघुनाथ। तब नारद मन हरष अति प्रभु पद
>   नायउ माथ ॥ ४२(ख) ॥
>
> evamastu muni sana kaheu krpåsindhu raghunåtha, taba nårada mana
>   harasa ati prabhu pada nåyau måtha. 42(B)
>
> **The all-merciful Lord of Raghus replied to the sage, "So be it"
>   Thereupon Nårada felt much delighted at heart and bowed at the Lord's
>   feet.**

Comment: I think this story is also present in some Puranas/ Scriptures because Tulsidas takes most stories of Ramcharitmanas from various Puranas...

Comment: And some people think Rama was not aware that He is incarnation of Lord Vishnu lol

Comment: @Tezz Oh I wasn't aware of that. The first reference I found was of Ramacharitmanas. So I just posted it. Do you know which puranas this story is is so that I could add it to my answer? :)

Comment: @Rishabh Haha. I think it all depends on perspective. Like Valmiki Ramayana's Rama was not aware he is divine while in Ramacharita-manas  Rama knew he was Vishnu Avatar. I believe that Rama knew of his divinity since how else could he achieve his goal of killing Ravana?