# Why "Rama" Nama is called Taraka mantra?

Tags: shiva, rama, moksha, name, om

At [Manikarnika Ghat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manikarnika_Ghat) of Varanasi (Kashi), Lord Shiva liberates the dead by saying "*Taraka mantra*" in ears of the dead. Many Puranas assert this fact.

*Chapter 30, Purvavadha , Kasi Khanda of Skanda Purana* says:

> O Pot-born Sage, without the knowledge that roots out Karmas, a person
>   who dies in Käsi becomes immortal, with the favour  of the
>   Moon-crested Lord.  With or without effort on one's part, one shall
>   abandon the body and die in Käsi. **Through the imparting of the
>   Täraka Mantra, he shall become immortal.**

*Chapter 33, Swarga Khanda of Padma Purana* also says Lord Shiva liberates by imparting Taraka Mantra. The great saint Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa [saw Lord Shiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16595/3500) liberating the dead by imparting Taraka Mantra.

Now, some authors translate Taraka mantra as "Pranava or OM" while others translate it as "Rama Nama". It is also popular belief that Lord Shiva says Rama nama in ears of the dead (at least among Telugu people).

From what i understood, Taraka mantra is mantra which takes us away from samasara  and hence mantra of liberation (tara = carrying across or crossing. Avatara also has tara and Ava means downwards).  It is easy to understand OM as mantra of liberation, as Om is [source of everything](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/749/3500).

[Name of **Rama**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20160/3500) is highly praised in many Puranas. It is also said many miracles were performed by [Neem karoli Baba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neem_Karoli_Baba) who used to chant Name of "Rama" always.

So, my questions are,

- Why Rama Nama is called Taraka Mantra? (Answers from scriptures are preferred but you  can also answer quoting words of Acharyas or Swamis).
- Do scriptures mention any other names or mantras which can be used as Taraka mantra besides name of Rama and OM?

**Note**: I'm not trying to demean Lord Shiva (i don't differentiate Shiva from Rama/Vishnu) or questioning greatness of name "Rama". Name of "Rama" is eternal and it is associated with many Lord Vishnu's avatars like Parasurama, Balarama not Ayodhya Rama alone. Considering cyclic nature of time, name Rama is eternal like Shiva/Rama/Vishnu. I'm just curious to know esoteric  meaning of word "Rama" pertaining to liberation.

Comment: Taraka Mantra is simply OM. Also sometimes mentioned in Agmas as Tritara.

Comment: @Rickross But i also heard many times Rama nama is Taraka Mantra. Even many Swamis/Pravachanakartas in Telugu states say Rama nama is Taraka Mantra or Taraka brahman. Hence this  question. :)

Comment: Well, in Agamas Mantras are not given directly. They are always mentioned in codes. And in the coded forms, the Mantras are said to start with Taraka or Tritara and we know that Mantras start with OM. So Taraka is well known to be OM only. If a Mantra is starting with Hrim, they will  mention Bhuvana Or Shakti instead of directly mentioning Hrim.

Comment: You can read this article: https://www.kamakotimandali.com/misc/mokshapuri.html

Comment: The 'taraka' mantra means a liberating mantra. With no context, it means the 'Om'. Like 'Chandas' literally means the grammatical construct while in some contexts it means the Vedas. The 'Avatara' literally means 'descent' and can be used when one is descending stairs or a horse. So it's quite context dependent.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned in Adhyatma Ramayana, I'll check it.

Comment: Note - Just giving one another ref.for" Lord Shiva liberates the dead by saying "Taraka mantra" in ears of the dead". It's from Muktika Upanishad.

Comment: I-i-18-23 -"Dying in the sacred Brahmanala in Kashi, he will get the Taraka-mantra and also liberation, without rebirth. On dying anywhere (else) in Kashi, Maheshvara will utter the Taraka-mantra in his right ear. " -http://www.vedarahasya.net/muktika.htm

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By Taraka Mantra we basically mean the Pranavam, the first sound or OM, also called the Nada Brahman.

So, Taraka: Deliverer.
Taraka Mantra: From the root word tara–that which crosses. The Taraka Mantra is that which enables 
its invokers to cross over the ocean of samsara and attain liberation.
Taraka Nama: The Delivering Name; Om

From Sannyasa Upanishad:

> That which is Om is the indestructible, the supreme and Brahman. That
>   alone should be worshipped. It  is this that is of the eight subtle
>   syllables. And this becomes eight, being of eight forms. ‘A’ is the
>   first  letter; ‘U’ is the second; ‘M’ is the third; Bindu is the
>   fourth; Nada is the fifth; Kala is the sixth;  Kalatita (that beyond
>   Kala) is the seventh; and that which is beyond these is the eighth.
>   **It is called  Taraka, because it enables one to cross this mundane existence. Know that Taraka alone is Brahman  and it alone should be
>   worshipped”.**
>
> 122. When confronted with a mass of sins (i.e. when the flesh becomes weak, over-ruling the dictates  of wisdom) he shall practise the
>        (meaningful) repetition of the Taraka (Om) twelve thousand times (a 
>        day); for it cuts (sins).

Now, it's mentioned in the Vedas themselves (viz in Sri Rudram) that Lord Rudra liberates.

> Namas taraya cha (prostrations to one who liberates)

And, it's also mentioned that Lord Shiva (or Rudra) is but Om in the Mantric level.

> "atha kasmAduchyata o~NkAro yasmAduchchAryamANa eva
>   prANAnUrdhvamutkrAmayati tasmAduchyate o~NkAraH "
>
> Rudra is called the personification of Pranva because he sends the
>   souls towards heaven, at the time of death (dissolution)
>
> **AtharvaSiras Upanishad 3.07**
>
> atha kasmAduchyate praNavaH yasmAduchchAryamANa eva
>   R^igyajuHsAmAtharvA~Ngirasa.n brahma brAhmaNebhyaH praNAmayati
>   nAmayati cha tasmAduchyate praNavaH||
>
> He is called the “one who has the shape of Pranava“, because the
>   Brahmins read and propagate the Rik, Yajur, Sama and Atharva Vedas
>   only after reading 'OM
>
> **AtharvaSiras Upanishad 3.08**
>
> "atha kasmAduchyate tAra.n yasmAduchchAramANa eva
>   garbhajanmavyAdhijarAmaraNasa.nsAramahAbhayAttArayati trAyate cha
>   tasmAduchyate tAram.h "
>
> He is called “Tara (Taraka - Liberator)” because he protects one from
>   the fear of life which consists of the fear of staying in the womb,
>   fear at time of birth, fear from diseases, fear from old age and fear
>   from death"

Quoted the above verses from [this page](https://www.facebook.com/shivatatva/posts/248770395251698) which basically discusses the same question as you are doing.

Same thing is stated in Puranas like Linga and Shiva.

> “Ishwara [the Lord] said: O dear sons, recite this Om mantra which is
>   identical with Me. Your knowledge shall be stabilized.” (Shiva Purana,
>   Vidyeshwara Samhita 10:32, 33)

So, when Lord Shiva himself is the liberator and his Mantric representation is Om or the Taraka why would he need any other Mantra or names?

Also, in Kashi Lord Shiva liberates the dead. This is bodiless liberation as opposed to Jivanmukti, where one attains liberation while living. And, the following passage states that bodiless liberation is attained by OM.

> Brahma asked: "Lord, what sort of a thing is the Brahman- OM?" 13
>   Narayana replied: "The Brahman-OM consists of sixteen morae [NpU 208].
>   It is within the range of the four quadruple states, since while awake
>   there exist the four states beginning with the state of waking, while
>   dreaming there exist the four states beginning with dreaming, in deep
>   sleep there exist the four states beginning with deep sleep, and in
>   the fourth there exist the four states beginning with the fourth [NpU
>   190 - 191, n. 84]. [286] In the state of waking there exist the four
>   forms of Visva: Visva-Visva, Visva-Taijasa, Visva-Prajfia, and
>   Visva-Fourth.14 In the state of dream there exist the four forms of
>   Taijasa: Taijasa-Visva, Taijasa-Taijasa, Taijasa-Prajfia, and
>   Taijasa-Fourth. In the state of deep sleep there exist the four forms
>   of Prajna: Prajna-Visva, Prajfia-Taijasa, Prajna-Prajna, and
>   Prajna-Fourth. In the fourth state there exist the four forms of the
>   fourth: Fourth-Visva, Fourth-Taijasa, Fourth-Prajfia, and
>   Fourth-Fourth. These reside respectively in the sixteen morae: the
>   waking-Visva in the phoneme a, the waking-Taijasa in the phoneme u,
>   the waking-Prajna in the phoneme m, the waking- Fourth in the
>   half-rnora, the dreaming-Visva in bindu, the dreaming-Taijasa in nada,
>   the dreaming-Prajna in kala, the dreaming-Fourth in kaldtita, the deep
>   sleep-Visva in sdnti, the deep sleep-Taijasa in sdntyatita, the deep
>   sleep-Prajna in unmam, the deep sleep-Fourth in manonmam, the
>   Fourth-Vi^va in pun, the Fourth-Taijasa in madhyamd, the
>   Fourth-Prajfia in pasyanti, and the Fourth-Fourth in para [NpU 208, n.
>   107]. [287] The four morae of the waking state are portions of the
>   phoneme a. The four morae of the dreaming state are portions of the
>   pho- neme u. The four morae of the state of deep sleep are portions of
>   the phoneme m. The four morae of the fourth state are portions of
>   the half-mora. **This indeed is the Brahman-OM. It should be worshipped
>   by Paramahamsas, Turiyatitas, and Avadhutas. Through it alone Brahman
>   is manifested. By means of it one attains bodiless liberation.**"
>
> **Paramhamsa ParivrAjaka Upanishad.**

So, Taraka is indeed the OM.

Another evidence:

> Lord Brahma told them: “Sudharshana (the holy wheel of Lord Vishnu) is
>   that great Chakra. **On its middle is written, the Taraka  mantra (OM)**
>   and also the single letter of Narasimha (Kshroum), on its six petals
>   of the Sudarshana six  letters (Sahasrara Hum Phat) are written, on
>   its eight petals the eight letters (Om Namo Narayanaya).
>
> **Nrisimha Purva Tapaniya Upanishad.**

Then from where did this idea crop up that Rama Nama is also Taraka?

The page linked above provides the following answer:

> However I wouldn't dismiss the claims of Vaishnava friends as unreal.
>   Since their claim is based on Rama Uttara tapini Upanishad verses
>   where it is said that lord Shiva did chanting of Rama's name in kashi
>   where becoming pleased with him Rama appeared and gave a boon saying
>   whosoever gets the "shadakshari" (six lettered mantra) from Shiva (in
>   ears) while dying would get liberated.. Vaishnava friends need to
>   grasp the Tatwam behind that story instead of reading it as it is.
>   P.R. Ramachander who translated the Rama Tapini Upanishad has
>   incorrectly mentioned the Shadakshari (Six letterred mantra) as "Ram
>   Ramaya Namah". The sanskrit version of the upanishad doesn't mention
>   this mantra at all. The upanishad mentions the following thing about
>   the Shadakshara which is TARAKA.
>
> "atha hainaM bhaaradvaajaH paprachchha yaaj~navalkya.n ki.n taaraka.n
>   ki.n taarayatiiti " (Ramatapini Upanishad-Poorvopanishat 6.2).
>
> "Sage Bharadwaja enquired Yajnyavalkya - 'What is Taraka? What is the
>   one which liberates?"
>
> Yajnyavalkya replied:
>
> "akaaraH prathamaaksharo bhavati ukaarodvitiiyaaksharo bhavati.
>   makaarastR^itiiyaaksharo bhavati. ardhamaatrashchaturthaaksharo
>   bhavati binduH pa~nchamaaksharo bhavati naadaH shhashhThaaksharo
>   bhavati . taarakatvaattaarako bhavati. tadeva taarakaM brahma tva.n
>   viddhi . tadevopaasitavyamiti j~neyam.h .
>   garbhajanmajaraamaraNasa.nsaaramahadbhayaatsa.ntaarayatiiti .
>   tasmaaduchyate shhaDakshara.n taarakamiti . . ya etattaarakaM brahma
>   braahmaNo nityamadhiite . sa paapmaana.n tarati . sa mR^ityu.n tarati
>   . sa brahmahatyaa.n tarati . sa bhruuNahatyaa.n tarati. sa sa.nsaara.n
>   tarati . sa sarva.n tarati . so.avimuktamaashrito bhavati . sa
>   mahaanbhavati . so.amR^itatva.n cha gachchhati " (Ramatapini
>   Upanishad-Poorvopanishat 6.2)
>
> "That which has 'A' as the first syllable, 'U' as the second syllable,
>   'M' the third syllable, half-note is the fourth syllable, dot is the
>   fifth syllable, and sound is the sixth syllable; that is called the
>   Taraka. That when practiced liberates one from the cycles of births
>   and deaths. This is verily the ' Shadakshara (Six letered)' Taraka
>   mantra namely Omkara. That person who regularly utters this Mantra, he
>   gets ferried from sins, he gets ferried from death, he gets absolved
>   of the sins like Brahmahatya (killing of brahmana), killing of foetus,
>   he gets ferried from the ocean of Samsaara, he gest liberated from
>   everything, he becomes one with the Avimukta (Lord Shiva as the
>   redeemer), he becomes great, he becomes immortal".
>
> **Hence it is clear that the Six-Lettered Mantra what Rama mentioned is
>   OMKARA.**

One can check the Sanskrit verses of Rama Tapaniya Upanishad from [here](http://upanishad.info/upanishads/text/atharvaveda/sanskrit/rama-tapaniya). One can also check the wrong translation given by P.R.Ramachander from [here](http://www.astrojyoti.com/ramatapaniyaupanishad.htm).

One reference, however, i got of Rama Brahma Taraka is from another minor Upanishad called Rama Rahasya:

> The great sages led by Sanaka asked Hanuman again, “Please tell us the
>   mantra for meditating (or  worshipping) the Taraka Brahma Rama.” 
>   Hanuman replied:
>   1. That king of mantra-s is the Ekakshara (one-syllabled) which is the store house of fire, which is Lord  Vishnu who is lying down and which
>   is Lord Shiva who adorned with the crescent moon. 
>   2. Its sage is Brahma, meter is Gayatri, Deity is Lord Rama, its anga is waxing half-Moon and its mind  is the soul of fire,
>
> **Rama Rahasya Upanishad.**

> Do scriptures mention any other names or mantras which can be used as
>   Taraka mantra besides name of Rama and OM?

Yes, some other minor Upanishad mentions the Mantra "Om Namo Narayanaya" also as the Taraka.

> Then Bharadvaja asked Yajnavalkya: “What is Taraka ? What is that
>   which causes one to cross (this  mundane existence)”. To which
>   Yajnavalkya replied: “Om Namo Narayanaya is the Taraka.
>
> **Tara Sara Upanishad**

EDIT:

Now, i have direct references from the Shiva Purana as regards which Mantra Lord Shiva whispers in the ears of the dead at Kashi in order to liberate them:

> 2. To understand the meaning of Pranava is to understand me. Pranava is the seed of all the lores.
> 3. It shall be understood as very subtle but possessed of great meaning even as the seed of the Banyan tree though very small contain»
>      a huge tree. It is the initial mantra and the essence of the Vedas.
>      Particularly it has me for its form.
> 4. I am the the lord beyond attributes, the omniscenet and the omnipotent. I am Siva pervading ail but stationed in the
>      single-syllabled mantra Om.
>
> 5. They say that whatever object there is whether synthesized into one or analysed in pieces is thc meaning of Pranava, thanks to the combination and importance of the attributes.
> 6. It is the imperishable Brahman, the means of attaining all objects. Siva creates universe at the outset saying "0m".
>
> 7. Since there is not much difference bctwecn thc sense and the sound 0m, this is explained thus. Siva is Pranava or Pranava is Siva.
> 8. The brahminical sages, the scholars who realize the identity between the sense and the sound know me as the single-syllabled 0m.
> 9. Hence he who aspires for salvation and is free from aberration shall understand Pranava the cause of all and me as the Nirguna
>      Paramesvara.
> 10. **O goddess, I shall give this crest-jewel of mantras at Käsi for the liberation of all Individual souls**.
>
> **Lord Shiva's words to Goddess Parvati in Shiva Purana's 2nd Chapter of Kailasha Samhita (Translated by J.L.Shastri)**

NOTE: The credit of finding these verses actually goes to The Destroyer :). I was unaware of them totally.

Comment: Good answer. But what could have made PR Ramachander to translate Shadakhari as "Ram Ramaha Namaha" in Ramatapini Upanishad-Poorvopanishat 6.2 when Sanskrit verses are clear? It's new thing to me that ॐ is also referred as  "Shadakshari".

Comment: @TheDestroyer Not sure. But i am aware of Ramachander's translations. Most of the Stotrams that i read are his transliteration and translation. But he often makes silly mistakes. In a Stotram called Durga Kavacham, he has entirely changed the first few verses. I can now see what the original verses were from my book Tantra Sara.

Comment: Shiva Purana says Shiva says Om in the ears of people who die in Varanasi and Padma Purana says it is Rama Nama. Both are words of Lord Shiva only. Which one should one believe?

Comment: //Hence it is clear that the Six-Lettered Mantra what Rama mentioned is OMKARA.//  So, it is the one-lettered Om that has the six letters embedded in it.  Is this a correct understanding of the explanation?  Thanks.

Comment: @vsubrahmanian If we count like A-first syllable, U-second syllable, M-third syllable, ArdhaChandra-4th, Bindu-5th and Nada-6th syllable then Om is six-lettered but usually its considered mono-syllabled or Ekakshara.

Comment: OK, thanks. Om assigned six syllables is difficult to accept/understand.

Answer (score 2):

According to Gurunathar,  HH SMS, RAMA is taraka Nama, obtained by conjoining Ra and Ma, obtained from the mantras Namo NaRAyanaya and NaMA Shivaya. Ra from Astaksharam and Ma from the Panchaksharam. Saint Sri Tyagaraja realised this. If you remove Ra and Ma, the jeeva aksharams from the Astaksharam mantram and Panchaksharam mantram respectively, they will lose meaning. Papa Ramadas, became Ramadas through the relentless repetitive chanting of Bhagavan Nama.  Jai Bhagavan Nama. Rama Rama. Watch [this short video](https://youtu.be/O7vA9DCtKMc), Sringeri Jagatguru's discourse about the greatness of Bhagavan Nama. Jai Rama Rama Rama Rama.

Comment: https://youtu.be/O7vA9DCtKMc

Comment: Welcome to [Hinduism.se]. You can [edit] your answer anytime and modify your answer. Add the video yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There will be no one who does not chant the name of Ram, whether it is Lord Shiva, Lord Shri Krishna or anyone else.The name of Rama is called Taraka Brahma because it is the name that takes you across this ocean of cosmos. Lord Shri Krishna glorified the name of Rama in such a way.

अथ श्रीपद्मपुराण वर्णित रामनामामृत स्त्रोत श्रीकृष्ण अर्जुन संवाद~

अर्जुन उवाच~

१)
भुक्तिमुक्तिप्रदातृणां सर्वकामफलप्रदं ।
सर्वसिद्धिकरानन्त नमस्तुभ्यं जनार्दन ॥

अर्थ:~ सभी भोग और मुक्ति के फल दाता, सभी कर्मों का फल देने वाले, सभी कार्य को सिद्ध करने वाले जनार्दन मैं आपको नमन करता हूं।

२)
यं कृत्वा श्री जगन्नाथ मानवा यान्ति सद्गतिम् ।
ममोपरि कृपां कृत्वा तत्त्वं ब्रहिमुखालयम्।।

अर्थ:~हे श्रीजगन्नाथ! मनुष्य ऐसा क्या करें कि उसे अंत में सद्गति हो? वह तत्व क्या है? मेरे पर कृपा करके अपने ब्रह्ममुख से बताइए।

श्रीकृष्ण उवाच~

१)
यदि पृच्छसि कौन्तेय सत्यं सत्यं वदाम्यहम् ।
लोकानान्तु हितातार्थाय इह लोके परत्र च ॥

अर्थ:~ हे कुंती पुत्र! यदि तुम मुझसे पूछते हो तो मैं सत्य सत्य बताता हूं, इस लोक और परलोक में हित करने वाला क्या है।

२)
रामनाम सदा पुण्यं नित्यं पठति यो नरः ।
अपुत्रो लभते पुत्रं सर्वकामफलप्रदम् ॥

अर्थ:~श्रीराम का नाम सदा पुण्य करने वाला नाम है, जो मनुष्य इसका नित्य पाठ करता है उसे पुत्र लाभ मिलता है और सभी कामनाएं पूर्ण होती है।

३)
मङ्गलानि गृहे तस्य सर्वसौख्यानि भारत।
अहोरात्रं च येनोक्तं राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम्।।

अर्थ:~हे भारत! उसके घर में सभी प्रकार के सुख और मंगल विराजित हो जाते हैं, जिसने दिन-रात श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षरों का उच्चारण कर लिया।

४)
गङ्गा सरस्वती रेवा यमुना सिन्धु पुष्करे।
केदारेतूदकं पीतं राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम् ॥

अर्थ~जिसने श्रीरामनाम के इन दो अक्षरों का उच्चारण कर लिया उसने श्रीगंगा, सरस्वती, रेवा, यमुना, सिंधु, पुष्कर, केदारनाथ आदि सभी तीर्थों का स्नान, जलपान कर लिया।

५)
अतिथेः पोषणं चैव सर्व तीर्थावगाहनम् ।
सर्वपुण्यं समाप्नोति रामनाम प्रसादतः ।।

अर्थ:~उसने अतिथियों का पोषण कर लिया, सभी तीर्थों में स्नान आदि कर लिया, उसने सभी पुण्य कर्म कर लिए जिसने श्रीराम नाम का उच्चारण कर लिया।

६)
सूर्यपर्व कुरुक्षेत्रे कार्तिक्यां स्वामि दर्शने।
कृपापात्रेण वै लब्धं येनोक्तमक्षरद्वयम्।।

अर्थ:~उसने सूर्य ग्रहण के समय कुरुक्षेत्र में स्नान कर लिया और कार्तिक पूर्णिमा में कार्तिक जी का दर्शन करके कृपा प्राप्त कर ली जिसने श्रीराम नाम का उच्चारण कर लिया।

७)
न गंङ्गा न गया काशी नर्मदा चैव पुष्करम् ।
सदृशं रामनाम्नस्तु न भवन्ति कदाचन।।

अर्थ:~ ना तो गंगा, गया, काशी, प्रयाग, पुष्कर, नर्मदादिक इन सब में कोई भी श्रीराम नाम की महिमा के समक्ष नहीं हो सकते।

८)
येन दत्तं हुतं तप्तं सदा विष्णुः समर्चितः।
जिह्वाग्रे वर्तते यस्य राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम्।।

अर्थ:~उसने भांति-भांति के हवन, दान, तप और विष्णु भगवान की आराधना कर ली, जिसकी जिह्वा के अग्रभाग पर श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षर विराजित हो गए।

९)
माघस्नानं कृतं येन गयायां पिण्डपातनम् ।
सर्वकृत्यं कृतं तेन येनोक्तं रामनामकम्।।

अर्थ:~ उसने प्रयागजी में माघ का स्नान कर लिया, गयाजी में पिंडदान कर लिया उसने अपने सभी कार्यों को पूर्ण कर लिया जिसने श्रीराम नाम का उच्चारण कर लिया।

१०)
प्रायश्चित्तं कृतं तेन महापातकनाशनम् ।
तपस्तप्तं च येनोक्तं राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम् ।।

अर्थ~उसने अपने सभी महापापों का नाश करके प्रायश्चित कर लिया और तपस्या पूर्ण कर ली जिसने श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षर का उच्चारण कर लिया।

११)
चत्वारः पठिता वेदास्सर्वे यज्ञाश्च याजिताः ।
त्रिलोकी मोचिता तेन राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम् ।।

अर्थ~उसने चारों वेदों का सांगोपांग पाठ कर लिया सभी यज्ञ आदि कर्म कर लिए उसने तीनों लोगों को तार दिया जिसने श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षर का पाठ कर लिया।

१२)
भूतले सर्व तीर्थानि आसमुद्रसरांसि च।
सेवितानि च येनोक्तं राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम् ।।

अर्थ~उसने भूतल पर सभी तीर्थ, समुद्र, सरोवर आदि का सेवन कर लिया जिसने श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षरों का जाप कर लिया।

अर्जुन उवाच~

१)
यदा म्लेच्छमयी पृथ्वी भविष्यति कलौयुगे ।
किं करिष्यति लोकोऽयं पतितो रौरवालये ।।

अर्थ~भविष्य में कलयुग आने पर पूरी पृथ्वी मलेच्छ मयी हो जाएगी इसका स्वरूप रौ-रौ नर्क की भांति हो जाएगा तब जीव कौन सा साधन करके परम पद पाएगा?

श्रीकृष्ण उवाच~

१)
न सन्देहस्त्वया काय्र्यो न वक्तव्यं पुनः पुनः ।
पापी भवति धर्मात्मा रामनाम प्रभावतः ।।

अर्थ~यह संदेह करने योग्य नहीं है, जैसे संदेह व्यर्थ है वैसे बार-बार वक्तव्य देना भी व्यर्थ है। कैसा भी पापी हो श्रीराम नाम के प्रभाव से वह धर्मात्मा हो जाता है

२)
न म्लेच्छस्पर्शनात्तस्य पापं भवति देहिनः ।
तस्मात्प्रमुच्यते जन्तुर्यस्मरेद्रामद्वचत्तरम् ।।

अर्थ~उसे मलेच्छ के स्पर्श का भी पाप नहीं होता, मलेच्छ संबंधित पाप भी छूट जाते हैं जो श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षरों का जाप करते हैं।

३)
रामस्तत्वमधीयानः श्रद्धाभक्तिसमन्वितः।
कुलायुतं समुद्धृत्य रामलोके महीयते ।।

अर्थ~जो श्रीराम से संबंध रखने वाले स्त्रोत का पाठ करते हैं तथा जिनकी भक्ति, विश्वास और श्रद्धा श्रीराम में सुदृढ़ है। वह लोग अपने दस हज़ार पीढ़ियों का उद्धार करके श्रीराम के लोक में पूजित होते है।

४)
रामनामामृतं स्तोत्रं सायं प्रातः पठेन्नरः ।
गोघ्नः स्त्रीबालघाती च सर्व पापैः प्रमुच्यते ।।

अर्थ~जो सुबह शाम इस रामनामामृत स्त्रोत का पाठ करते हैं वे गौ हत्या, स्त्री और बच्चों को हानि पहुंचाने वाले पाप से भी बच कर मुक्त हो जाते हैं।

(इति श्रीपद्मपुराणे रामनामामृत स्त्रोते श्रीकृष्ण अर्जुन संवादे संपूर्णम्)

Answer (score 1):

> Why Rama Nama is called Taraka Mantra? (Answers from scriptures are preferred but you can also answer quoting words of Acharyas or Swamis).

As the words of Acharyas can also be quoted, [here is a video message on this topic from Sri Vidhushekhara Bharati Swami, the Shankaracharya of Sringeri](https://youtu.be/udg39ysAAVI?si=rBOO9h1sJ0V8UUS-)

Gist of Swamiji's message (in Hindi).

> (starting) The greatness of the divine names of Bhagavan is unparalleled. And even amongst the names, the significance of the holy name of Bhagavan Sri Rama is infinite. That is why we call this mantra as Taraka mantra.

> (around 1:30, after quoting a sloka) When I chant the name of Sri Rama, I do not need to fear even death. This is the meaning of the sloka. That is why the holy name of Sri Rama is called as Taraka mantra.

> (around 2:50) This is the Taraka mantra - Sri Rama Jaya Rama Jaya Jaya Rama.

Answer (score 0):

**ओमिति ब्रह्म।**

(Shruti or vedas)

Om is the Tarak brahm

**रामनाम्नः समुत्पन्न प्रणव मोक्षदायकः।।**

(Maha ramayan)

Ram naam is the originator of pranav "om"

Hence Ram naam is also a Tarak brahm

**श्रीराम रामेति परं जाप्यं तारकं ब्रह्मसंज्ञकम्।**

(Sanatkumar samhita)

Shri ram is best japak mantra and is Tarak brahm mantra.