# Is there any short and powerful Saraswathi naama/mantra available for Sudras?

Tags: scripture, mantras, name, saraswati, shudra

There are several names/mantras available for Sudras that are very powerful. I am using the word 'powerful' to stress that the mantra is capable of giving both temporal pleasures and eternal moksha.

I know a few names that are available for Sudras that are powerful enough. For example '[Rama](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22726/why-rama-nama-is-called-taraka-mantra)', '[Namah Sivaya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16418/661)' etc., are *Taraka* in nature and also surely give temporal pleasures to the Sadhaka of the mantra.

In this context, I want to know whether there are any such short mantras/names of Maa *Saraswathi* available for all humans that are also powerful.

Comment: There is the Vagvija but it is prohibited to recite any Shakti mantra without having undergone diksha in atleast one Shakti mantra.